# 1.9 - Shopping Cart Price Rule - Buy any x + y + z Reduce total price to $399

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

Could anyone please help me to setup up below price rule?

Apply if any category1 + category2 + category3 + category4 in cart. Reduce total price to $399.

Quick reply will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you access the official document first before asking? http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html

Comment: How do you know they haven't read the documentation first?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using core magento shopping cart rules. It's only possible to specify the amount of discount to be applied not the final figure.

You may need to look at a commercial extension for this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/108892)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/108892)

Comment: @dhiren The poster asked how to do it. I have said it's not possible and explained why. Why is that not an answer? It's not appropriate to put that in a comment because I'm not asking for clarification.

Comment: @jai there is no link in my answer.

Comment: This does not provide answer and it's link like answer. Your answer come to review as it was flagged as low quality answer by community members. My above comment is default message-template from review system.

Comment: I suggest you to add this type of answers as comments so that community members don't flag. Thank You